# Debugging winMobile application on remote device (PDA, ARM) from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, windows-mobile, remote-debugging, windows-ce

*Hi!*

I have some PDAs (windows mobile) to test my application. One of them is HTC Touch Dual, and it have some [bugs in debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473535/). There is another ARMv6 device I can use, but it's far far away. So I can't use USB cable, but can use **TCP/IP** (internet, not intranet).

Do you know, how can I **connect to remote windows mobile device to debug** application on it?

We tried different ways and now we know this:

1. ActiveSync is bad. It disables all external connections to device and it's impossible (or just I don't know how) to remotely debug device while it's connected via ActiveSync.
2. We have created VPN, connected device via wi-fi to remote PC, and setup routes to device be accessible over VPN. At this step device can be connected without ActiveSync ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228708.aspx)) from Visual Studio on remote PC. But connection from Visual Studio on my PC was not available - "device not ready". I can ping device, but can't connect it from Visual Studio.

I've checked following things:

- binaries versions to connect without ActiveSync to be correct as said in MSDN article above
- routers/firewalls don't block anything
- device is ready to debug
- sniffed packets to device looks similar in case of remote PC connection and my PC connection, but somehow my PC establish only 1 connection, while remote 2

I think, VPN and PDA connection without ActiveSync was very close to get remote debug, but something goes wrong with it. Maybe I just need some sleep now :)

And the questions are:

1. Do you know, **how to debug remote winCE application in a simplier way?**
2. **What a problem** can be **with "VPN method"** if it's the simplest way?

*Thank you.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve this via CoreCon... After Microsoft moved from EVC to Visual Studio they deprecated Platform Manager in favour of CoreCon.

Take a look under C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\CoreCon\1.0\Target\wce400[targetarch].

Basically you run ConmanClient2.exe and then CMAccept.exe which opens a window of time in which you can establish a TCP/IP connection via the IDE.

You can override the need for CMAccept.exe via adding the reg key  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CoreConOverrideSecurity=DWORD:0x01.

After CoreCon is running on your target device, you need to point the IDE to the Device via the 'Device Options'/'Properties'/'Transport'/'Configure'/'Use specific IP address'. Simply set the IP to that of the device.

I have found CoreCon much faster and reliable than the old EVC infrastructure - the debugger definitely benefits from it. It has its fair share of limitations, but it doesn't depend directly on ActiveSync which more than makes up for it! :)

Comment: I have no such folders; the furthest I get is: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared - no CoreCon after that...

Comment: Look in `Program Files (x86)` if you're on a 64-bit machine