# Connect Visual Studio 2008 to Windows Mobile 6.5 Device via LAN

Tags: visual-studio-2008, compact-framework, windows-mobile-6.5

I'm developing software on Windows Mobile 6.5 handheld devices and my problem is, that I have no cradle to connect the device to USB (via ActiveSync).

So I have two possibilities:

Connecting the device via Bluetooth. This solution is very slow and application files are not the smallest.

Connecting the device via LAN/WLAN. Can anybody tell me how to connect Visual Studio 2008 to the device? There are solutions for WM5 and older but I can't find a solution for WM6.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Debugging winMobile application on remote device (PDA, ARM) from Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474355/debugging-winmobile-application-on-remote-device-pda-arm-from-visual-studio)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I think you have to initially build up a connection over cradle and after that you can debug with wireless. A cradle is very helpful, also with other issues.