# How can I debug a CE app on the device?

Tags: c#, debugging, windows-ce, postmortem-debugging, handhelddevice

I asked a similar, but not identical, question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23251972/why-is-my-ce-app-refusing-to-run)

My Windows CE app won't even start up on the handheld device (an old version of it does, but not the new version).

It builds, copies over, but just refuses to run; it "flashes" when I 2-click it, but that's it. No err msg, just won't budge.

I added a global exception handler in hopes it would catch the problem and give me a glimpse into it with this code:

```
public static int Main(string [] args)
{
    try
    {
        // A home-brewed exception handler (named ExceptionHandler()) is already 
defined, but I'm adding a global
        // one for UNHANDLED exceptions (ExceptionHandler() is explicitly called throughout the code in catch blocks).
        AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
        currentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(GlobalExceptionHandler);

        . . .

        // Instantiate a new instance of Form1.
        frmCentral f1 = new frmCentral();
        f1.Height = devIn.GetScreenHeight(); 
        f1.Text = SSCS.GetFormTitle("The Return of Sancho Panza", "", "");

        Application.Run(f1);

        devIn.Close();

        Application.Exit();
        return 0;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        SSCS.ExceptionHandler(ex, "Main");
        return 0;
    }
} 

static void GlobalExceptionHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
{
    Exception e = (Exception)args.ExceptionObject;
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("GlobalExceptionHandler caught {0}", e.Message));
}
```

...but still no go; there is nary a peep to be heard from the little guy.

Is there anything I can do to find out what is happening / why the little beast refuses to respond to its wakeup call?

### UPDATE

Could the problem be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23226794/how-can-i-resolve-the-invalid-resx-file-cannot-find-valid-resheader-tags-fo), and if so, how to solve it?

The circumstance that both the updated version of this existing app AND [a brand new and simple app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23251972/why-is-my-ce-app-refusing-to-run) refuse to run indicate there is something fundamentally flawed somewhere in the coding, building, or deployment process.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Debugging winMobile application on remote device (PDA, ARM) from Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474355/debugging-winmobile-application-on-remote-device-pda-arm-from-visual-studio)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate; I don't necessarily want to do what that post refers to. I simply want to find out why the .exe won't run anymore. Perhaps my post title was not the best. I don't mean "debug" as in have a live connection with the IDE, necessarily. I mean "debug" as in, How can I determine what is failing? By adding code, by looking in some location on the device to see what's been dumped there, or something like that would be fine.

Comment: I see, I'll retract the vote then.